Burninate the "biography" tag
The usage guidance for biography says: "Questions about biographies, i.e. publications that provide a detailed description of a person's life." But the questions using this tag are all over the place:

Asking for biographical details of an author's life, e.g. Did William Somerset Maugham's uncle treat his nephew in an emotionally cruel way?
Asking how autobiographical some works are, e.g. How autobiographical are Laura Ingalls Wilder's Little House books?
Asking about legends associated with historical figures, e.g. Origin of the story of Gilbert and the Saracen maid.

None of these is about biographies! A couple of questions do actually follow the usage guidance, e.g. How was Jon Meacham able to complete his biography of John Lewis so quickly?, but on the whole the tag is pretty useless. Especially since Literature Stack Exchange has (misguidedly, IMO) chosen not to use genre tags, it is not clear what purpose biography serves, when it's used in such an imprecise manner. None of the questions would lose anything by having that tag removed.

I wrote that tag wiki excerpt in 2017 and it has never been modified or challenged, so if we continue using it, we should at least use it correctly.
I am open to deleting it, since "biography" is unlikely something that someone follows or specialises in across languages.
